# Limitations of assertEqual

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) for `assertEqual` in Python `unittest` say

> `assertEqual(first, second, msg=None)`
>
> Test that first and second are equal. If the values do not compare equal, the test will fail

If my inputs, `first` & `second` are deep nested objects (e.g. dict of list of dict and list etc.), are there any limitation to what cannot be compared with the above assert statement? So far, I know that if at any depth, there's a list, its order has to match on both sides (because that's how I would normally compare a list).

There's no specific mention of nested objects in the docs and I couldn't find a clear answer to it.

Comment: It seems likely to me that `assertEqual(a,b)` would have behavior equivalent to `assert a == b`. the `==` operator works on nested collections, so `assertEqual` should, too.

Comment: Is that in the docs for equality operator? I've seen a handful of gists on github for various implementations of nested comparisons, hence wondering where does the default equality operator fall short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertEqual` calls the appropriate [type equality function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) (if available).  e.g. `assertEqual` on lists actually calls [`assertListEqual`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual).  If no type equality function is specified, `assertEqual` [simply uses the `==` operator](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1addc4f0f10c/Lib/unittest/case.py#l501) to determine equality.

Note that you can make and register your own type equality functions if you wish.

If you want to look at the actual implementation, `assertListEqual` simply delegates to `assertSequenceEqual` which [ultimately uses `!=` to compare items](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1addc4f0f10c/Lib/unittest/case.py#l690).  If the sub-items are nested, it gets compared however python compares those items.  For example, lists are considered equal if:

> Sequence types also support comparisons. In particular, tuples and lists are compared lexicographically by comparing corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, every element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length. (For full details see Comparisons in the language reference.)

See the docs on [python sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: Does `==` operator have any limitation on nested objects then? a dict of dicts/lists etc. etc.

Comment: @user4150760 -- For builtin containers (list, dict, tuple, set, ...), it all works pretty much how you expect.  e.g. to compare 2 lists of lists you check the first list in each to see if they are equal, then the second, then the third, ... lists of lists of lists will work similarly (it's just 1 more level of recursion).